# how to show that entire function is a polynomial?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $\displaystyle f$ be an entire function such that
>   $$\lim_{|z|\rightarrow \infty} |f(z)| = \infty .$$ Then, Prove  that
>   $f$ is  polynomial.

My attempts: I was thinking about $f(z)  = \sin z$ but it is not polynomial as I am confused.

Please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Moreover, $|\sin(x)|\leq 1$ for $x\in\mathbb R$. Hence $|\sin(z)|\to\infty$ for $|z|\to\infty$ doesn't hold.

Comment: @Winther: You are right. I falsely interpreted that the converse was true.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: let $g(z)=f(1/z)$ for $z \ne 0$.

If $f(z)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ for $z \in \mathbb C$, then

Then $g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{z^n}$  for $z \ne 0$.

From $\lim_{|z|\rightarrow \infty} |f(z)| = \infty $, we see that $g$ has a pole at $z =0$.

Can you proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for some $r > 0$, $0 < |z| < r\implies f(1/z)\ne 0$ (why?). Let be $h(z) = 1/f(1/z)$ for $0 < |z| < r$, $h(0) = 0$. You can prove easily that $h$ is holomorphic in the disk $|z| < r$ and has a zero of order $m > 1$ at $z = 0$, i.e.,$1/h$ has a pole of order $m$ at $z = 0$. How is the Laurent series of $1/h(z) = f(1/z)$ at $z = 0$?